# Looking for datasets of RNA-Seq (or scRNA-Seq) for L1 larvae C. elegans

Tags: rna-seq, scrnaseq, wormbase

I was wondering if anyone know of a repository for C. elegans data sets, specifically in L1 larvae stage.

Are there any papers or GEO-sets for this organism at this stage?

thanks

Assa

Answer (score 0):

See WormBase, which has a number of different resources for different nematodes:

https://wormbase.org